# Python POST not working

Tags: python, post, urllib

I am trying to send POST data from a python script to a url. Here is the code:

```
def createperson(self,name=None):
        SERVER_BASE_ADDR = 'http://localhost:8000/'
        postdata = urllib.urlencode({'name':name})
        req = urllib2.Request(SERVER_BASE_ADDR + 'people/add')
        fd = urllib2.urlopen(req,postdata)
        return name
```

But this returns

```
HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: INTERNAL SERVER ERROR
```

Adding a person on the url is fine. Any ideas?

EDIT

The server side uses django decorators to handle POST and GET.

```
@require_http_methods(["GET", "POST"])
def add(request):
       if request.method == "POST":
           #do stuff with post data
```

Isn't the above python code the same as submitting a form on a html template? If its the same then shouldn't the handlers handle it the same way?

Thank you

Solved by using:

```
c = urllib2.build_opener()
postdata = urllib.urlencode({'name':name})
r = c.open(url,postdata)
```

A different approach but does the job. Thank you for all your answers.

Comment: What are you using to handle the request on the server side? Does it require a trailing slash / ? Does your server give you any feedback about why its failing the request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTTP 500 error means that the problem doesn't occur on the client-side python script, but on the server side.

Check your server side code, maybe it reads data only from GET, not POST.

Comment: Please view the edit in the question. I have django decorators to handle POST and GET requests

Comment: Sorry I am pretty new to django, but i suggest you print out (or log) the posted data. If data is posted successfully, then it must be the server side code.

Answer (score 2):

HTTP 500 errors are definitely internal server errors.  The problem occurs on the server, as @dlutxx has pointed out.

To debug this further, I think you should examine your Django handler.  If it really does work for GET requests but not POST requests, perhaps you should look at what is different between the GET handler and the POST handler.

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

@require_http_methods(["GET", "POST"])
def add(request):
    try:
        if request.method == "POST":
            # Something is probably broken here.
        elif request.method == "GET":
            # But apparently works fine here.
    except:
        # Why don't we insert some debugging output to try to catch it.
        logger.exception("Problem in add handler")
        raise
```

EDITed to use Python logging framework (per [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/)) instead of stdout.

Comment: It gives a 500 internal server error before even hitting the server code. I have put the code above but I just get [10/Feb/2012 16:00:00] "POST /people/add HTTP/1.1" 500 57486 on the server

Comment: My demo code sent the traceback to stdout, which your Django server probably didn't capture for logs.  Try using logging instead (edited my answer).

Comment: Nope, no matter where I put the logger on the server side script it does not even reach there before showing the 500 server error.

Comment: @Jimmy: Then your server is not working at all.  This question is irrelevant to your real problem, which is that your server code is broken.

Comment: @S.Lott: But the server works fine when I access it through a browser. It just doesn't work when I try to access POST requests using the python code in the question.

Comment: @Jimmy: If it raises 500 error then -- by definition -- it does not work.  If any -- any! -- request leads to a 500 error, the server is broken.  You need to debug the server.  If you can't insert logging, then you have middleware problems or other configuration issues which you must solve.  This is **entirely** a server problem.  Nothing else.